# apt update can't find http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/mutter/mutter_42.9-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, mutter

I ran apt update today after maybe 6 months and it can't find mutter_42.9-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb. If I browse the archive URL with Firefox, I can see the following:

```
mutter_42.9-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb  2023-09-15 13:14    105K
```

should I be installing this by hand? Or is there some other fix

Comment: What version of ubuntu? in 22.04 it's mutter_42.9-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb What actual problem are you facing?

Comment: `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*` and `sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*` Then refresh `sudo apt update && sudo apt -f install`

Comment: The packages are not erased on the main archive, but when you `sudo apt update` your software lists stored on your machine will updated to reflect the latest available on the servers. I see a likely incomplete issue with your execution of `sudo apt update` (did you stop it? get warnings/errors you ignored?) or you have an outdated package you forced install & haven't upgraded (put a hold on for example) that requires this outdated package. Work out your release & read all messages, check holds etc.

Comment: Thanx, rm-ing /var/lib/apt/lists/* worked.